# Create a Logger Library in java

Tags: java, logging

I would like to create a  logger class library. The requirements are

1. Write the log in a file in a specified path
2. Change the path of Log file
3. Write the log in system console
4. Write debug mode to the log file
5. Generate separate log for WARNING, ERROR and INFO messages.

How can I begin this with out extending the Log4J or logger or any other built in libraries. Any guidance would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which of above requirements is not satisfied by `Log4J`?

Comment: This is WAY too broad of a question for SO. Also, if you are asking these kinds of questions its a pretty sure chance that this might be too ambitious a project you are undertaking.

Comment: It is licensed under Apache. I would like to create a free library.

Comment: i'd begin by looking at how logback is designed :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be simpler to just using log4j, java.util.logging, logback or some other existing Java logging framework.  They are all capable of satisfying your requirements as stated.

---

This is apparently your beef ...

> It is licensed under Apache. I would like to create a free library.

The simple response to that is that Apache software is free, and the license is pretty permissive.  If you have a specific issue with the Apache license, why not just use java.util.logging ... which is licensed under the same terms as your Java platform.

---

> Any guidance would be grateful.

Well apart from the above (i.e. don't waste your time ...), if you really want to implement a new logging framework, you should start by researching existing ones to understand what they do, how their APIs are designed and how their implementations work.  (Otherwise you are going to produce something that nobody will want to use.)  It would also help to find and read comparisons and critiques of the different frameworks.

That research should tell you where you need to start.  If not, then you are probably not skilled / experienced enough to do this task yet ... try something simpler.